# css alignment issues in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: css, cross-browser, microsoft-edge, angular-bootstrap

I am trying to make my application cross-browser compatible. While testing in Microsoft Edge browser I found out that Edge calculate width in a different manner as compared to all other browsers. for eg. the buttons appear distorted in Edge while displaying perfectly in all other browsers(Chrome, Firefox, IE11).
[image: display in Microsoft Edge browser]

[image: display in chrome/IE11]

Quick hack that can be done is detect Edge browser and apply width specific to it. But I do not think that it would be an optimal solution. Can anyone suggest better solution for it? 
If i set width to be 22% then it displays fine in Edge browser but chrome display breaks. So that solution too is out :( 
Please help!

```
<div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-no-trans">
        <i class="icon icon-dashboard"></i>
        <span translate>
            Manage Dashboards
        </span>
    </button>



    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-no-trans" id="editDashboardBtn">
        <i class="icon icon-pencil"></i>
        <span translate>
            Edit Dashboard
        </span>
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-no-trans">
        <i class="icon icon-trash"></i>
        <span translate>
            Delete Dashboard
        </span>
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-no-trans">
        <i class="icon icon-refresh"></i>
        <span translate>
            Refresh
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I am not applying any additional css to any of the buttons. It has default bootstrap styling

Comment: Post the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce this please.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/), its basically a HTML5 IE enabling script and that should get bootstrap working in IE 6,7 and 8. This can also be directly hot linked like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

It must be included before the <body> element (i.e. in the <head>)

Comment: Check your viewport also it Shoud be like this.   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

Comment: Will it work for Microsoft Edge? Bootstrap is working fine with IE11 its just edge that is acting weird.

Comment: The solution you suggested didn't work. I checked viewport, it seems correct-<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge, chrome=1"/>

Comment: what's that? i told you give your fiddle not copy pasted from somewhere?

Comment: and that too is working fine even if i add 12 rows. here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/girish28892/DTcHh/32229/